# Validation issue with <link> tags with media query inside

Tags: html, css, webkit, media-queries, w3c-validation

I have this piece of code within my link tag:

`media="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)"`

Which displays my website in a different way when using a Retina device, however, when I validate it via W3 Validator, I get this error:

> Bad value (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), ↩  (min-resolution:
>   192dpi) for attribute media on element link: Expected a letter at
>   start of a media feature part but saw - instead.

Any ideas how I can get around this error?

Note: I didn't insert the carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some unprintable character there. Try typing this fragment again and don't use carriage returns

Comment: Hi, I didn't insert that, that was the result I got from W3 Validator.

Answer (score 0):

One trouble with vendor-specific, experimental implementations (indicated by dash-prefixed properties) is that they *are* invalid.

You can either:

- wait for the feature to be standardised and supported *or*
- leave it invalid *or*
- (for some features) dynamically modify the attribute with JavaScript so that the validator won't see it (so you'll still be invalid, you'll have more complex, hard to maintain code but the validator won't see your deviations from the spec).